# No 4k playback option in YouTube on lower resolution screens?

Tags: youtube

I'm using lower than 4k resolution screens and just noticed that the 4k option is missing in the YouTube player, even on videos specifically tagged 4k.
Does anyone else experience this issue and maybe even know the cause?
I tested in Firefox and in Edge.

Comment: This sounds like *good design*, not something that's broken.

Comment: Since the 4k option is the only one with the greater color depth, it also has  advantages on lower resolution screens. Besides, taking options away may look good, but is never good design regarding the user experience.

Comment: Does it work in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4K option is available again (at least in `Firefox 63.0.1`). I suppose only Google knows what really happened...